# Electron.NET Tray Icon - Click to show app instead of opening tray menu

Tags: c#, electron, blazor, tray, electron.net

C# Blazor with Electron.NET
Tray icon opens tray menu regardless of if it's right or left click.

How do I disable opening the menu when it's a normal (left) click and make it just show the app instead?

**This is what I want to happen when the tray is left clicked**:

```
Electron.WindowManager.BrowserWindows.First().Hide();
```

Instead, it shows a menu like this:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIKot.png)

Comment: As per sources (https://github.com/ElectronNET/Electron.NET/blob/master/ElectronNET.API/Tray.cs), there are `click` event for tray icons, which may be handled as you want. Did you tried this?

Comment: Electron.Tray.OnClick += (TrayClickEventArgs, Rectangle) => { Electron.App.Exit(0); };
Electron.Tray.On("click", () => { Electron.App.Exit(0); });
This is what I've tried so far: nothing happens.